# Set a limit to each shard?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So below is the current code I am trying to work with in setting up shards for my bot. I currently am able to get 3 online but is there a way I can set the limit to each shard?

1. C:\Desktop\Test Bot>node .
   Launched shard 0
   Bot is online!
   Launched shard 1 Bot is online! Launched shard 2 Bot is online

   ```
   const { ShardingManager } = require('discord.js');
   const manager = new ShardingManager('./bot.js', {
       token: '-----',
       totalShards: 3 
   });


   manager.on('shardCreate', shard => console.log(`Launched shard ${shard.id}`));
   manager.spawn();
   ```

I am trying to find out how I can set a limit of 1,500 guilds per shard?

Comment: Or in this case can I use ‘auto’ and it’ll cap the shards for me?

Comment: Nope, if I recall correctly 'auto' should use the *soft* limit I mentioned, dividing the number of guilds your bot is in by 900 (the recommended guild count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Discord API does not allow this sort of functionality.** And there is quite a feasible reason why.

The whole purpose of 'sharding' is to enable you to split the processing load evenly between a controlled amount of processes/worker threads.

**When you enforce a guild limit for shards, you are basically nullifying those two key factors of sharding:**

- splitting the load evenly
- being able to control the amount of shards

For example, let's say you want a *hard* 1500 guild limit on your shards, and 5 shards. Your bot is in 10,000 guilds.

What would happen is:
---5 shards in total ---

- Shard A: 1500 guilds
- Shard B: 1500 guilds
- Shard C: 1500 guilds
- Shard D: 1500 guilds
- Shard E: 4000 guilds

Or, if you just wanted a hard limit of 1500 guilds:
-- 7 shards in total --

- Shard A - F: 1500 guilds
- Shard G: 1000 guilds

**If you want a *soft* limit however, you can just perform ceiling-division on the number of guilds your bot is in by the limit you want, and then spawn the relevant amount of shards.**

```js
Math.ceil(10000 guilds / 1500 limit)
```

Would be equal to 7 shards with about 1430 guilds in each of them.